# Documenting Layered Architecture with PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

I want to document layered software architecture with plantUML that at the end will look like this:

[image]

**What will be the best approach to create this type of diagram with plantUML?**

[This](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/VTF1QeGm40RWUvuYuDM0asYy5KlfhQVUYaWH4zlIDH4tonuMttq32SkYPkOa_pU7cP4qPzSlxZAToCVhr_ldjw2i_VrJIfjEsQjXDCGyCZzc86JkX__-HyT0q1kXlWOxpTPeu-YR_n95ZDSZ10mvXkA1wtOGxcdRpyCOwnuW1Jm58WLb2geKo1JK4NRBmU6L0Rio08OSGu5XYM65eSImVlwpyU2ipQIlSSoLTKwhxYMk7Hh0DmJ8isMd1MMfG9966-MVmXq0) is the initial what I came up with, which represents 3 layered architecture with some generic components. (please check the link)
[image]

```
@startuml
LAYER_3 -[hidden]down- LAYER_2
LAYER_2 -[hidden]down- LAYER_1

package LAYER_3 {
    component Comp30 {
    }
    component Comp31 {
    }
    component Comp32 {
    }
    component Comp33 {
    }
}

package LAYER_2 {
  component Comp20 {
  }
  component Comp21 {
  }
  component Comp22 {
  }
  component Comp23 {
  }
  component Comp24 {
  }
  component Comp25 {
  }
  component Comp26 {
  }
  component Comp27 {
  }
}

package LAYER_1 {
    component Comp10 {
    }
    component Comp11 {
    }
    component Comp12 {
    }
    component Comp13 {
    }
    component Comp14 {
    }
    component Comp15 {
    }
    component Comp16 {
    }
    component Comp17 {
    }
}

Comp23 -[#6666ff,dotted]> Comp10
Comp21 -[dotted,#red]> Comp10
Comp20 -> Comp10
Comp20 -> Comp16
@enduml
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post some code.

Comment: It will hard if not impossible to get that ellipse around the arrows, overlayed on the horizontal layers. I have used plantuml inside drawio drawings, to do hybrid diagrams.

Comment: Here's a hybrid example: https://github.com/fuhrmanator/log210-ndc-quarto/blob/main/images/MDD-Risk-contrats.drawio.svg

Comment: @albert this is how I started [code](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/duml/VTF1QeGm40RWUvuYuDM0asYy5KlfhQVUYaWH4zlIDH4tonuMttq32SkYPkOa_pU7cP4qPzSlxZAToCVhr_ldjw2i_VrJIfjEsQjXDCGyCZzc86JkX__-HyT0q1kXlWOxpTPeu-YR_n95ZDSZ10mvXkA1wtOGxcdRpyCOwnuW1Jm58WLb2geKo1JK4NRBmU6L0Rio08OSGu5XYM65eSImVlwpyU2ipQIlSSoLTKwhxYMk7Hh0DmJ8isMd1MMfG9966-MVmXq0)
One of the problems is that I can NOT align them to represent proper layers.

Comment: Please cut and past the code into the question, so other can also easily see it.